# How to search for or navigate to a Java file type in IntelliJ IDEA 13?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

How do I navigate to or search for a particular file type in IntelliJ IDEA?

For example, I need to search for all *abstract* classes in my project, or all the *interfaces* in my project, or all the *enum* files in my project.

Is there a shortcut such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: I would also recommend to watch the official video tutorial by JetBrains: [Navigation in IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cv-84klCL7Q)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't mention whether you have the ultimate edition or not. If so, you can use Intellij's structural search feature. You can invoke it with `<CTRL>-<Shift>-S` or by navigating to `Edit->Find->Search Structurally`.

To find all interfaces, use this template: `interface $Interface$ {}`. The `$Interface$` part is a variable and can be parameterized with a regular expression so you can narrow down your search. The same principle applies for abstract classes and enums.

Structural search is a powerful feature, make sure to take a look at the existing predefined templates.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my requirements :) found other wonderful search templates too. just for the reference I am using the ultimate version

Answer (score 4):

Press 2 x Shift and type what you searching for

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is not what you are looking for but it works: use textual search Ctrl-Shift-F:

`"interfeace "`
`"enum "`
`"abstract class"`

If you want you can even use  regex serarch, e.g. `"abstract\s+class"`

EDIT:

There is smarter solution for enums: open `java.lang.Enum` class and press `Ctrl-Shift-B`.