# How to search for an Enum file type in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, enums

I'm using IntelliJ 16. I know I can find *classes* by `Ctrl+N` and *files* with `Ctrl+Shift+N`, and I'm also aware of [Structural Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26526238/how-to-search-navigate-for-to-a-java-file-type-in-intellij-13), but I want to search with enum's name (not listing all enums or all files).

Is there a way to **search for an Enum** file in IntelliJ (with shortcut keys)?

Comment: Search tirelessly to find out :(

Comment: Turns out this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72535419

Answer (score -2):

Sometimes plain string search works well. Try search `enum` using "Find in Path" (`CTRL+SHIFT+F` or `CMD+SHIFT+F`). Notice the space before and after `enum`, you can adjust the search keyword depending on your code style.