# Is there any way to get all the enums classes and their respective values from a project in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, enums

I need to create a list of classes declared as enum in a project in IntelliJ and, inside each one, list the respective values. Is there any automated way to accomplish this task, as it is a rather large project, with hundreds of occurrences.

Comment: I dont know a way within intellij directly but a small script with classpath reflection would do the trick. Scan for all classes that are enums and get all available values from it.

Comment: Please feel free to create a feature request for the issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this using the type hierarchy view and export the entries to a file. I'm using eclipse shortcuts and I can open the type hierarchy using `F4`. Just make sure to filter `Production` files.

Example using the Guava project:

[image: All enums within the project]

As for getting all the values for each enum, I don't think there's such a feature in IntelliJ, but you could probably write a script to process the exported file.

**Edit**

This method will print enum values using the file exported from IntelliJ. You might need to modify it to handle errors, etc.

```java
    private static void printEnumClassesAndValues(String file) throws IOException {
        Files.lines(Path.of(file))
                .filter(line -> !line.contains("java.lang"))
                .map(line -> {
                    String[] tokens = line.replaceAll("[\\(\\),]", "").trim().split(" ");
                    return String.format("%s.%s", tokens[1], tokens[0]); // package + class name
                })
                .forEach(enumClass -> System.out.printf("%s: %s%n", enumClass, Arrays.toString(getEnumValues(enumClass))));
    }

    private static Enum<?>[] getEnumValues(String enumClass) {
        try {
            Method m = Class.forName(enumClass).getDeclaredMethod("values");
            return (Enum<?>[]) m.invoke(null);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex); // log or handle otherwise
        }
    }
```